# Mongoose: Add validators on the fly on some parameters depending on queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am new to Mongoose and would like to know if it is possible to **add validators on the fly on some parameters depending on queries**. I have for example a schema like below:

```
var user = new Schema({
     name: { type: String, required: true },
     email: { type: String, required: true },
     password: { type: String, required: true },
     city: { type: String },
     country: { type: String }
});
```

For a simple registration i force users giving the name, the email and the password. The Schema on top is OK. Now later I would like to force users giving the city and the country. **Is it possible for example to update a user's document with the parameters city and country on required?** I am avoiding to duplicate user schema like below:

```
var userUpdate = new Schema({
     name: { type: String },
     email: { type: String },
     password: { type: String },
     city: { type: String, required: true },
     country: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you would need to do in this case is have one Schema and make your `required` a function which allows `null` and `String`:

```
var user = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: function() {
      return typeof this.city === 'undefined' || (this.city != null && typeof this.city != 'string')
    }
  }
});
```

You can extract this and make it an outside function which then you can use for `county` etc.

What this does is it makes the field required but also you can set `null` to it. In this way you can have it null in the beginning and then set it later on.

[Here is the doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-required) on `required`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that link. I think i will do it like this. I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no, it is not possible.

Mongoose schema are set on collection, not on document.
you could have 2 mongoose model pointing to the same collection with different Schema, but it would effectively require to have duplicated Schema.

personnally, in your situation, I would create a single home-made schema like data structure and a function who, when feeded with the data structure, create the two version of the Schema.

by example :

```
const schemaStruct = {
    base : {
      name: { type: String, required: true },
      email: { type: String, required: true },
      password: { type: String, required: true },
      city: { type: String },
      country: { type: String }
    }
    addRequired : ["city", "country"]
}
function SchemaCreator(schemaStruct) {
     const user = new Schema(schemaStruct.base)

     const schemaCopy = Object.assign({}, schemaStruct.base)
     schemaStruct.addRequired.forEach(key => {
          schemaCopy[key].required = true;
     })
     const updateUser = new Schema(schemaCopy);
     return [user, updateUser];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The answer of @Akrion is what i really need (avoiding duplicate). I will upvote for your effort.